# For-loop on object names

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

There is probably a very simple way of doing this, but this is a programming niggle I've had for a long time but never thought there might be an answer to.

Consider the following:

```
[someButton1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[someArray objectAtIndex:0]]];
[someButton2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[someArray objectAtIndex:1]]];
[someButton3 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[someArray objectAtIndex:2]]];
[someButton4 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[someArray objectAtIndex:3]]];
[someButton5 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[someArray objectAtIndex:4]]];
[someButton6 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[someArray objectAtIndex:5]]];
... etc
```

I know I can use a `For {...}` loop to provide the array indexes, but is there any way of iterating through the button names programmatically, i.e someButton1, someButton2 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the buttons themselves in an array and iterate over it.

Comment: Ok so assuming that I'm not a complete dolt for not even contemplating doing this! I'd use something like: [[buttonArray objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:[someArray objectAtIndex0]]; right?

Comment: yes, but instead of `0`, use the iterator (`i` or whatever) as an index for both arrays.

Comment: Okay got it. I'm still completely amazed (and slightly embarrassed)  that I didn't twig this one a little sooner. Thanks for making me wake up! :)

Comment: I have set up the code as you suggested but trying to set the title like this: [[indexButtonArray objectAtIndex:i] setTitle:@"Sometitle"]; it gives me the error -[UIButton setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e43da0. I can set whether the button is enabled, but it crashes setting the title. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I've fixed it! Had to use "forState:UIControlStateNormal" as well! Working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, using introspection, but you don't need to, simply create an array of buttons and iterate it in the same way you iterate the array of strings...